# Android how to find the correct bluetooth server

Tags: android, bluetooth

According to Android Bluetooth documentation ([Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)), when the client calls `BluetoothAdapter#startDiscovery` and subsequently get a `BluetoothDevice`, it should first call `BluetoothAdapter#cancelDiscovery` before it attempts to call `createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord` because `startDiscovery` uses too much bandwidth that might cause the connection to fail if it's running concurrently. However, how do you know which `BluetoothDevice` is the server you are trying to connect to?

I don't understand how this can avoid the loop where you start discovery, finds a device (not your server), cancels discovery and tries to connect to the device, fails, re-start discovery, and repeat.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution I came up with is to keep track of the addresses of all the `BluetoothDevice` that you already tried to connect with and failed, and on the next attempt of `startDiscovery` simply bypass those. However, I am still calling `startDiscovery` and `cancelDiscovery` multiple times and discovering the same wrong devices multiple times, so I would love to hear a better solution if anyone has one!